# Laplace transform of a differential equation??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Find unique solution of $y′′ + y = f$ using $y(0) = y′(0) = 0$ and periodic function $f(t) = t$  if $0 \leq t < 2\pi$

Attempted work:

$L[y'' + y ] = L[f(t)]$

$L[y''] + L[y] = L[f(t)]$

$s^2 L[y] -sy(0) -y'(0)+L[y] = L[f(t)]$

$(s^2 + 1) L[y] = L[f(t)]$

I only managed to do that much. I am having trouble with the periodic function and setting up the right hand side of the equation. I am trying to set it up as an integral. I would really appreciate for any help setting up this equation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be easier to solve for general initial conditions on the interval $[0, 2 \pi)$ and then create a solution with new initial conditions $\lim_{t \to 2 \pi} y(t), \lim_{t \to 2 \pi} y'(t)$ and repeat...

Comment: Alternatively, you could expand $f$ in terms of its Fourier series, and then solve the above for $f(t) = e^{2 \pi i n t}$ and add. Justifying convergence is a little trickier, though. If you do pursue the Laplace transform approach, this will suggest the form of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is $T$-periodic. Then
$({\cal L} f)(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{nT}^{(n+1)T} f(t) e^{-st} dt$, and using the substitution $\tau = t-nT$ and the fact that $f$ is $T$-periodic, we get
$\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T} f(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_0^T f(\tau)e^{-s(\tau + nT)} d \tau
= e^{-s nT} \int_0^T f(\tau)e^{-s\tau} d \tau $, and so, using
$1+x+x^2+\cdots = {1 \over 1-x}$, we get
$({\cal L} f)(s) =  {1 \over 1-e^{-sT}}\int_0^T f(\tau)e^{-s\tau} d \tau $ (with $\operatorname{re} s > 0$).

We have $T=2 \pi$, and $f(t) = t$ (for $t \in [0,T)$), so 
$\int_0^T f(\tau)e^{-s\tau} d \tau = {1 \over s^2}(1-(1+2 \pi s)e^{-2 \pi s})$, and so
$({\cal L} f)(s) = {1 \over s^2(1-e^{-2 \pi s})} (1-(1+2 \pi s)e^{-2 \pi s}) $.